# Can't clone a repository using TortoiseGit

Tags: git, github, version-control, tortoisegit, msysgit

I'm trying to clone a git repository using the **TortoiseGit** I'm running on windows platform and I have installed the TortoiseGit 1.7.13.0, when I try to clone the repository I'm getting the following error message

"Disconnected: No Supported authentication methods available (Server sent: public key)"

Can some one help me to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

drop down to git bash and issue the clone command from there. It will be easier to get help if this doesn't work. AFAIK, tortoise uses MSysGit underneath.

Comment: tried in git bash, and it's shows the permission denied error, i was able to fix it by following this link https://help.github.com/articles/error-permission-denied-publickey thanks

Comment: Git clone is working from Git Bash but not with TortoiseGit. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try logging into GitHub with `ssh -T git@github.com`

If it doesn't work check if you have made your SSH key known using `ssh-add path/to/key`

Make sure you have keys in your .ssh directory